# How to run perf in Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to run perf in bash on Windows 10 (creators update, so Ubuntu 16.04), but I get the following error:

`perf not found for kernel 4.4.0-43`

Then it suggests a couple of package I need to install, but when I try I get the following error:

> E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-4.4.0-43-Microsoft
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-4.4.0-43-Microsoft'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-4.4.0-43-Microsoft'

How can I fix this?

[image: wsl error missing package ubuntu 16.04]

Answer (score 0):

WSL is a minimal shim that translates Linux kernel calls into Windows runtime calls. You can't possibly expect a full implementation.

For example, it is 64-bits only and won't execute 32-bit binaries regardless what compatibility libraries you install.